# Get a qrcode scanned image in onActivityResult using zxing in android

Tags: android, zxing

I am scanning the qrcode successfully and displaying the result url into the textview following.
`etxt_qrcode.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));`
Now i want to display the scanned image into imageview.I don't know exactly what i want to do.Is zxing return anything related to image to display imageview or tell me the process to display the result scanned image into imageview.please give me a needful help i am struggling from past two days on this.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a way to do it. The image is not returned. The problem is that the image can be quite large to parcel. But with downsampling and compression, probably not a big deal. I'd entertain a patch if you want to work on it. http://code.google.com/p/zxing

Comment: Hi sean firstly thanks for your reply.i am working on zxing itself.i downloaded zxing and adding as a library of my application and calling the CaptureActivity intent.Is there any other way to do the requirement what i posted earlier.thanks

Comment: If you're going to copy our code, please see https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/LicenseQuestions . Just cloning it is not OK. But if you are legitimately reusing part of the code here, look at the points in CaptureActivity where it sets the thumbnail image into the view. That's the small grayscale image you want.

Comment: Exactly but the thing is i cannot able to access bitmap object into my application.why because it is library project if i am doing any modifications on library project no effect into the application.For example i created one bitmap object and i am trying to access that bitmap object from actual application class but i cannot.

Comment: Finally i got the output.I defined CaptureActivity bitmap object globally and accessing the bitmap object in application activity class.thanks sean for giving support.

Comment: @malli Sorry to bump your post after a long while, can you share how you made this work? I am also interested in getting the scanned image of the barcode in an application I am writing.

Comment: @SeanOwen Can you please point me in right direction. I am trying to scan multiple barcodes at once. Saw this [MultipleBarcodeReader.java](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/multi/MultipleBarcodeReader.java). But problem is, I am not sure how to force ZXing to use this class. A little insight about this will be much appreciated.

Comment: You just use the class as the reader directly in your code. The command line tool exposes it with --multi I think.

Comment: @SeanOwen I can't figure out, how to scan multiple barcodes from a live camera feed. Please a few more details from you would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by the following:
 first before start intent set :
**setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);** 
and after that you will get image path in OnActivityResult like following:
**String path=intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_IMAGE_PATH");**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There may be no direct way to get the image from the intent extras but there is a workaround that may help, after you get the decoded string you can convert it to image again. here is a code to do so,

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            if (scanResult != null) {
                generateQRCode(scanResult.getContents());
            }

        }
    }

public void generateQRCode(String data){
        com.google.zxing.Writer wr = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            int width = 350;
            int height = 350;
            BitMatrix bm = wr.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

                    mBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mBitmap != null) {

            img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
    }
```