# Android ZXing - saving the scanned image using CaptureActivity?

Tags: android, zxing

I have an Android Application where I use ZXing Library to scan barcodes and get the data written in them.  In addition, I would like to save the photo of the scanned barcode image that ZXing scanned.  If one looks closely, you can see that the ZXing Library "freezes/pauses" the camera input when it manages to read the barcode.

[I've seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786143/get-a-qrcode-scanned-image-in-onactivityresult-using-zxing-in-android) from 2 years ago where someone attempted to play with the ZXing library.  I tried to extend `CaptureActivity` instead of `Activity`, however, I am getting the error:

> Cannot inherit from final
>   'com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity'

and now I'm unsure on how to go about this.

Is it possible to get the Image that the Barcode Scanning Application of ZXing reads?  Did ZXing eventually incorporate this feature and patch it?  I can't seem to find any guides online on how to get the image that was "captured".  It will make my Android Application run more seamless.

Answer (score 0):

While leading for years, you might want to consider using Google's API, then you can save the camera snapshot yourself.

https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview

Comment: Just to implement a proof of concept app with QR code scanning. Works fine.